# Instantiate a generic type with every key of a different type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a working 'solution' but it's very ugly and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner one. The code I have written is something along the lines of the following, this accomplishes my goal of getting typescript to correctly infer the type of `value` in each of the branches of the switch statment.

```js
type Foo = {
  key1: string
  key2: number
  key3: {message: string}
}

type FooProperty<Key extends keyof Foo> = {
  key: Key,
  value: Foo[Key],
}

type FooPropertyData = FooProperty<'key1'> | FooProperty<'key2'> | FooProperty<'key3'>

const func = (change: FooPropertyData) => {
  switch (change.key) {
    case "key1": {
      return change.value.toUpperCase()
    }
    case "key2": {
      return change.value * 8
    }
    case "key3": {
      return change.value.message
    }
  }
}
```

However this requires you to manually add every key of `Foo` to the `FooPropertyData` type. which is clearly not ideal. My first thought would be to do something like:

```js
type FooPropertyData = FooProperty<keyof Foo>
```

But this loses type safety. Is there a better way to do this?

Apologies if the title is misleading I'm new to generic types and am not exactly sure how best to word it.

Comment: In other words, you want to distribute the union instead of passing the entire union as one to a type. This can be done with the unintuitive `T extends T ? ... : never` as you can see in my solution. Working on an explanation for why this is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make TypeScript use each constituent of `keyof Foo` separately:

```
type FooPropertyData<T extends keyof Foo = keyof Foo> = T extends T ? FooProperty<T> : never;
```

This phenomenon can be demonstrated in the following:

```
type All<T> = Set<T>;

type Each<T> = T extends T ? Set<T> : never;

type AllIn = All<"1" | "2">; // Set<"1" | "2">

type EachIn = Each<"1" | "2">; // Set<"1"> | Set<"2">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA1hEARgC4oBnYAJwEsA7Acyx3xACZTaBXAWwCMJKTPAQDMpVNwhkyAQ3oRSFGgwC+WNZiyhIsBAAVKcSJVAAeANIEoEAB7AItACZlhIOADNdcAHzI0QllJLEAAaIQA3GQAbTgUvAG1ggF0wzA0tcGh4OAMjAVAAERlgGVMAFWs7B2dXDy8-Fjrs3xQK23snFwqAfi9c4zMy3w4IcIEAbiwAeimobSz9QwGQIpK-bP78kFMAchZCHd8AHz6lrd2WVkOoE42zk2290UOsDJ0AQSio8paoAGUIMAfpNNJh5lAAKIyADGAAsfn42lVOlAev9AQiRmNKCC3tBPlEAJK0PwE0wAIkI5JuUHJrHJ3nGUBm6KBlOpJzpDOmsxwAD1uq8wZlITDYcS-FC4RSqTSuYzmbMAWyqcdWRT6d4eTgoAKhdC4LQKFB3JxaNC-AAKOEyBhxO55B6rGQASmQvgw2HIAHdqMA4VBrbDbfIAHQsN2enVQaEyMjQcn7cniITRyiAziUEk2u2hyIxCCh4BwACqYGMAGE4xBLS7U1ANNHY-HaZdk-4vWmM1mY8Hc-nYlAAFRQAAc9cbOubCZYInbUejUHTwEz2b7YYHhck0jkEAnQg0KiAA)

Comment: Yup, it's called as "Distributive property of Conditional types over naked type parameters". We can achieve this same in many ways `T extends T...` , `T extends any`, `T extends unknown ` and so on...